# Div height variable based on top and bottom position

Tags: html

I'm working with a twitter widget.
CSS for SITE

```
#site {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 1000px;
height:100%;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
top:-20px;
box-shadow: 2.5px 4.33px 29px 0px rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
}
```

Here's my CSS for DIV

```
#twitter-widget-0  {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
width:220px;
height: auto;
top:50px;
bottom: 100px;  
}
```

I would like the height to fill the area in between the bottom and top position.

For example if the webpage size was 800px by 2000px. Then the twitter div height would become 1850px, or if the height of the page was 1000px the div would be 850px.

Answer (score 1):

```
#twitter-widget-0  {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
width:220px;
height: auto;
margin-top:50px;
margin-bottom: 100px;  
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I even added a min-height. Thinking that might help. Instead it just stays at the min-height.

Answer (score 0):

Where is problem?

For check problem needed see code for outer area.

I think for fix you should just add `position:relative;` to outer area style.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/DYtBE/